# Creating an off-heap in-memory ChronicleMap

Tags: chronicle-map

Testing out off-heap caching with ChronicleMap. Will this code create an off-heap in-memory map?

```
chronicleMap = ChronicleMapBuilder.of(String.class, ByteBuffer.class)
     .entries(aMaxSize)
     .averageKeySize(100)
     .averageValueSize(1000)
     .create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any instance of ChronicleMap is off heap, it may be file-backed (memory-mapped file) or not, but in any case it will store data off heap.